# Need to write multiple csv files to new folder

Tags: python, csv, pandas, transpose

I haven't been able to find any information on this topic here, and would really appreciate your help! I'm pretty new to python, but here's what I have.

I have multiple file in a folder, and want to read them, transpose them, and then rewrite them into a new folder. I think I have everything going, but can't figure out how to rewrite everything.

here is my code:

```
path = 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Clemson\Pleurodires\stability data\Es03\fixed\processed'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
for filename in filenames:
    dfs = (pd.read_csv(filename))
    df = dfs.transpose()
    df.to_csv('transposed\' + 'Tr_' + filename)
```

the last line (i hope) should put all the new files in the folder called 'transposed', adding a Tr_ in front of the name which was loaded initially (ie if the file name was 'hello' it would now be 'Tr_hello' inside of the folder transposed).

What is happening when I run the code above, is that it says it works, but then the files don't exist anywhere in my computer. I've tried playing around with a variety of different ways to get the df.to_csv to work and this is the closest I've gotten

***Edit***

Thanks for everyone's help, I ended up combining a mix of Nanashi's and EdChun's code to get this, which works: (the final files are in the correct folder, and are called Tr_filename)

```
path = r'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Clemson\Pleurodires\stability data\Es03\fixed\processed'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
for filename in filenames:
    short = os.path.split(filename)
    newfilename = 'Tr_%s' % short[-1]
    #print newfilename
    dfs = (pd.read_csv(filename))
    df = dfs.transpose()
    df.to_csv(os.path.join('transposed', newfilename))
```

Comment: What is the issue? Are you getting an error? Or are the files writing to the incorrect location? Or not writing at all?

Comment: Hi Cyber, thanks for your help, I don't get an error, but the files aren't writing at all (at least I can't find them anywhere on my computer).

Comment: Have you tried changing your `to_csv` call to something like `df.to_csv(path + '\transposed\' + 'Tr_' + filename)`

Comment: I don't see how that code will even run.  Isn't the to_csv line a SyntaxError?

Comment: @c_mayerl please print the output from filenames and also I would construct your destination path and file and print it before you call `to_csv` to confirm it looks right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. `filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")` -- unless I'm wrong, that should be a backslash, not a forward-slash. Forward slashes are primarily used in Unix systems, etc. but definitely not in Windows where path names are concerned.
2. Try printing out `filename`. It will give you the whole path as well. At the `df.to_csv` line, you're actually writing to `path + filename + transposed + Tr + filename`. You have to isolate the specific filename (using `split` or the `os` module may work).

I'm using Ubuntu, so this might not apply that accurately, but here's how I'll do it.

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

path = "/home/nanashi/Documents/Python 2.7/Scrapers/Scrapy/itbooks"
filenames = glob(path + "/*.csv")

for filename in filenames:
    specname = filename.split("/")[-1]
    print filename
    print specname
    dfs = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df = dfs.transpose()
    df.to_csv("transposed/%s" % specname)
```

Result:

```
/home/nanashi/Documents/Python 2.7/Scrapers/Scrapy/itbooks/realestateau.csv
realestateau.csv
/home/nanashi/Documents/Python 2.7/Scrapers/Scrapy/itbooks/itbooks.csv
itbooks.csv
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

Screenshot of transposed file:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Nanashi, thanks for your help. I have tried doing as you suggested, and I don't get an error, but also don't get any file. Perhaps it is because I'm using windows, as it looks like it works perfectly for you! Printing out filename does show all of the files that i want to transpose though.

Comment: Kindly check if your backslashes are escaping anything. Also, is it alright if you edit your post and append your updated code? :)

Comment: It's been done! thanks for all your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: Don't forget to mark any of our answers as accepted if it solved your issue or upvote them if you found them helpful. This is how we say thanks in SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have multiple errors try the following:

```
import os
path = r'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Clemson\Pleurodires\stability data\Es03\fixed\processed'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
for filename in filenames:
    dfs = (pd.read_csv(filename))
    df = dfs.transpose()
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(r'transposed\Tr_', filename))
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice EdChum, I've tried it, and it looks like it successfully transposes my files, but doesn't create any new ones.